# Why doing assignment does not make objects to point same location

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

I am trying to understand the concept of copy constructor. With copy constructor I get desired result. But with out copy constructor I get the same result. The code is given here:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x1, int y1) { x = x1; y = y1; }

    // Copy constructor
    // Point(const Point &p2) {x = p2.x; y = p2.y; }
    void set()
    {
        x=50;
        y = 100;
    }
    int getX()            {  return x; }
    int getY()            {  return y; }
};

int main()
{
    Point p1(10, 15); // Normal constructor is called here
    Point p2 = p1 ;
    // p2 = p1;
    cout << "p1.x = " << p1.getX() << ", p1.y = " << p1.getY();
    cout << "\np2.x = " << p2.getX() << ", p2.y = " << p2.getY();
    p2.set();
    cout << "\np1.x = " << p1.getX() << ", p1.y = " << p1.getY();
    cout << "\np2.x = " << p2.getX() << ", p2.y = " << p2.getY();
     // Copy constructor is called here

    // Let us access values assigned by constructors
    return 0;
}
```

The out put is :

```
p1.x = 10, p1.y = 15
p2.x = 10, p2.y = 15
p1.x = 10, p1.y = 15
p2.x = 50, p2.y = 100
```

Shouldn't it be :

```
p1.x = 10, p1.y = 15
p2.x = 10, p2.y = 15
p1.x = 50, p1.y = 100
p2.x = 50, p2.y = 100
```

Edit 1 : What if I initialize objects like this:

```
Point p1(10, 15); // Normal constructor is called here
    Point p2(11,10);
    p2 = p1;
```

Will it call copy constructor? If not, why in this case the result is the same?

Comment: Why?  `p2` is a copy of `p1`.  Note if you don't provide a copy constructor the compiler provides one for you.

Comment: what if I don't want to use a copy constructor? Does C have such facility?

Comment: Then you can make one and make it private or if you have C++11 then you can delete it.

Comment: @khanshah _"what if I don't want to use a copy constructor? "_ You may be interested in [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: One more thing, does copy constructor makes two object to point same place?

Comment: @khanshah _"does copy constructor makes two object to point same place? "_ No.

Comment: I meant default copy constructor.

Comment: @khanshah Neither! A copy is a copy, and therefore a different object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ makes a distinction between *objects* and *references* to objects. If you want

`p2` and `p1` to point to the same `Point`, you should do this:

```
Point& p2 = p1;
```

Because you never defined a copy constructor for your `Point` class, the compiler gave you one. It will effectively look like this:

```
Point(const Point& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y)
{}
```

And your code, `Point p2 = p1` will call this copy constructor.

This causes the integer values to be copied, not point to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 2):

> But without copy constructor I get the same result.

This is because you get a default copy constructor and a default assignment operator inserted for you by the compiler. It does precisely the same thing as your hand-written copy constructor does, so there is no need to code one manually.

> Shouldn't it [the optput] be ...

No, it should not. In your code `p1` and `p2` are different unrelated objects, even though the initial state of `p2` comes from `p1`.

You need to use pointers or references to get the behavior that you want:

```
// Point p2 = p1;
Point& p2(p1);
```

Now `p2` behaves as an "alias" for `p1`, so there is really one object.

[demo](http://ideone.com/YUPghB)

Comment: then why should I write my own copy constructor, If compiler provides the one?

Comment: @khanshah Yes, why should you? But your question actually leads into some different direction, asking why the result receives a different address.

Comment: @khanshah The main reason for writing your own copy constructor (as well as your own destructor, and your own assignment operator)  is to manage resources that you *manually* allocate in the constructor (e.g. by calling `new`). When your classes consist of primitive members and/or members with copy constructors that suit your purposes, there is no reason to write your own copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor is called usually in cases of declaration and initialization of object to another object at same time, or while passing to functions. What the first statement means is:

```
Point p1(10,15);
Point p2(p1);
```

Is an example of usage of copy constructor while,

```
Point p1(10,15);
Point p2;
p2=p1;
```

is just plain assignment.
And No. Your output is right in the first case. A copy constructor just copies the values of one object into another, it doesn't make the new one a reference object.
Also, the main use of copy constructor is usually in functions.
As a footnote, to understand constructors and when they are called, you could use different cout statements in them. Then you'll know when a particular constructor is called.
P.S. I'm a beginner, so please tell me if I've got anything wrong.